# Race condition on pthread_kill()?

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix

Linux manual for pthread_kill() has the following paragraph:

> POSIX.1-2008 recommends that if an implementation detects  the  use
> of  a  thread  ID  after  the  end  of  its  lifetime, pthread_kill()
> should  return  the error ESRCH.  The glibc implementation returns
> this error in the cases where an invalid thread ID can be detected.
> But note also that POSIX says that an attempt to use a thread ID whose
> lifetime has ended  produces  undefined behavior, and an attempt to
> use an invalid thread ID in a call to pthread_kill() can, for example,
> cause a segmentation fault.

The problem is, between checking the thread ID is valid and issuing the `pthread_kill()`, the thread might have terminated. Is it inherently unsafe to use `pthread_kill()`, as there is always a race condition that can turn into a undefined behavior?

How to ensure thread ID will be valid?

Comment: Just to be precise, the thread must be terminated _and_ either joined or detached for its now invalid thread ID to present this race.  In strict POSIXy language, a [terminated thread is still within its lifetime](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html#tag_16_435_08) and is merely "inactive" (no longer running but not yet detached/joined).  That said, good question.

Comment: `between checking the thread ID is valid and issuing the pthread_kill(), the thread might have terminated` You mean, __inside__ `pthread_kill` call? That's simple - `pthread_kill` has internal global lock so it doesn't happen, no?

Comment: @KamilCuk Not inside `pthread_kill`, but between my `if` that decides to call `pthread_kill` and the call itself.

Comment: Why would you check it? Just call `pthread_kill`?

Comment: Usually something triggers `pthread_kill` on a thread ID I have reasons to believe is valid. But between the triggering and the call, a detached thread might have ended.

Comment: `a detached thread might have ended` So don't call `pthread_detach` on it when you intent to send `pthread_kill` later? Indeed with detached thread, that's a problem, but you should not ever do anything with detached thread, just because the thread ID can become invalid anytime. So don't make it detached. How do you detect if thread is running after `pthread_detach`??

Comment: There is no possibility to check if  thread is running in POSIX. There is no race-condition, as you just can't write an `if` that decides the call to `pthread_kill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Race condition on pthread_kill()?

When the thread is detached, always. But if thread ID is valid, no.

> Is it inherently unsafe to use pthread_kill(), as there is always a race condition that can turn into a undefined behavior?

No, not always.

> How to ensure thread ID will be valid?

From [POSIX thread ID](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_02):

> The lifetime of a thread ID ends after the thread terminates if it was created with the detachstate attribute set to PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED or if pthread_detach() or pthread_join() has been called for that thread.

Otherwise it's valid. So when the thread is not detached nor joined, thread ID is just valid and you always at any time can call `pthread_kill()` with it.

Generally, you should **stop using** a thread ID after `pthread_detach` or `pthread_join`. It's like `free()` in `malloc()` - you can't use memory allocated by `malloc()` after `free()`. The same way you can't use thread ID after detaching or joining, the thread ID just becomes invalid. Just with `pthread_detach` it becomes invalid "later", but you don't know when, so you can't use it anyway (well, unless you write your own synchronization). It might become invalid right after the call to `pthread_detach`. If you intent to do **anything** with a thread ID, do **not** detach and do not join it.

The call to `pthread_kill` with "inactive thread" (non-detached non-joined thread that terminated) is **valid** - the thread ID is still valid. We can read from [pthread_kill posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html):

> Existing implementations vary on the result of a pthread_kill() with a thread ID indicating an inactive thread (a terminated thread that has not been detached or joined). Some indicate success on such a call, while others give an error of [ESRCH]. Since the definition of thread lifetime in this volume of POSIX.1-2017 covers inactive threads, the [ESRCH] error as described is inappropriate in this case. In particular, this means that an application cannot have one thread check for termination of another with pthread_kill().
>
> FUTURE DIRECTIONS
>
> A future version of this standard may require that pthread_kill() not fail with [ESRCH] in the case of sending signals to an inactive thread (a terminated thread not yet detached or joined), even though no signal will be delivered because the thread is no longer running.

The `FUTURE DIRECTIONS` looks like it's prefering that `pthread_kill()` with an inactive thread should just succeed and return 0. I personally like the `ESRCH` error in such case.

Answer (score 1):

> *How to ensure thread ID will be valid?*

You must redesign so that your code knows this *a priori*.*  Anything short of that is a [TOCTOU race (CWE-367)](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html).

Fortunately, there's a lot of prior art from *interprocess* `kill`ing.  Interprocess signaling doesn't run the terrifying risk of undefined behavior like `pthread_kill` does, but careful coders consider the risk of signaling a recycled PID just as unacceptable.  (And thread IDs [can be recycled, too](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_02).)

* OK, you *could* do it by checking some contrived state.  For example, set a *mutex-protected* `i_am_still_running` flag to false at the very, very end of your thread routine.  Then only `pthread_kill` that thread while holding the mutex and confirming that it is still running.  Yuck.